# Using Where condition with Upsert Query in Gorm GoLang

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am trying to use where condition using upsert query in Gorm GoLang but the upsert query is not getting formed correctly. It is just updating the values without where condition.
Here is my code -

```
onConflict := clause.OnConflict{
        Where:     clause.Where{Exprs: []clause.Expression{clause.Lte{Column: "timestamp", Value: time.Now()}}},
        DoUpdates: clause.AssignmentColumns([]string{"first_name", "last_name", "timestamp", "updated_at"}),
    }
insert := gormSQLDB.Clauses(onConflict).Create(&Users)
```

The mysql query formed from above code is -

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`first_name`,`last_name`,`timestamp`,`updated_at`,`id`) VALUES ('Ram','Kumar','2022-05-03 03:59:16','2022-06-07 14:45:22.631','5befa85e-e642-11ec-89a5-acde48001122') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `first_name`=VALUES(`first_name`),`last_name`=VALUES(`last_name`),`timestamp`=VALUES(`timestamp`),`updated_at`=VALUES(`updated_at`)
```

My requirement is to update the row on the basis of same id field with where condition as timestamp should be lower than current timestamp. But the where clause is not working. Can anybody tell me what is wrong in my code?

Comment: did you find any solution for this?